# Springfox Spring Boot UI not accessible: Unabled to Infer Base URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, springfox

I am using Spring Boot: v2.0.3.RELEASE and Spring Fox: v2.9.2.

Trying to access http://127.0.0.1:8080/swagger-ui.html results in:

> Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet
>   registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is
>   the root of where all the swagger resources are served. For e.g. if
>   the api is available at http://example.org/api/v2/api-docs then the
>   base url is http://example.org/api/. Please enter the location
>   manually:

Repeatedly clicking OK in the popup bar has no effect.

Here is my Spring Security Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    private SecurityProperties securityProperties;
    private AppProperties AppProperties;

    public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                             BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder,
                             SecurityProperties securityProperties,
                             AppProperties AppProperties) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        this.securityProperties = securityProperties;
        this.AppProperties = AppProperties;
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public class BasicAuthenticationConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .antMatcher("/admin/**")
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .httpBasic().and()
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN").and()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser(AppProperties.getAdminUsername())
                    .password(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(AppProperties.getAdminPassword()))
                    .roles("ADMIN");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public class TokenAuthenticationConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.
                    cors().and().csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/no-auth/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(securityProperties, authenticationManager()))
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "**/swagger-resources/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**")
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        }

        @Bean
        CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
            CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
            corsConfiguration.applyPermitDefaultValues();
            corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
            corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "DELETE"));
            corsConfiguration.setMaxAge(3600L);
            final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
            return source;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the SpringFox configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Autowired
    private AppProperties AppProperties;

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer mvcConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

                registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("foo-api")
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .produces(Collections.singleton("application/json"))
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Foo API")
                .termsOfServiceUrl(AppProperties.getApiTosUrl())
                .version("1.0").build();
    }
}
```

In my Spring-Security Configuration, I have tried to exclude all Spring-Fox paths as generally advised but it doesn't have any effect. What is going wrong?